# Oracle 11g - Retries login attempt

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g, which settings that allow user to retries login attempts before oracle revoke password ? for instance, I want to allow user set login attempts to five, if user tried > five times that Oracle revoke his/her password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [PROFILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm) in Oracle, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROFILE MY_APP_PROFILE 
   FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 5;

ALTER USER MY_USER PROFILE MY_APP_PROFILE;
```